# How to Change vertical spacing in list items in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gui

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I found that text size and spacing is too much and I want to reduce the vertical spacing in list view of a folder.

Setting > Universal Access > Large Text option is off

icon size set to 20 from Appearance > Dock

but that does not change file icon and folder icon.

someone please help me how can I do that?

[image: vertical spacing in list items in ubuntu 20.04]

Comment: The spacing depends on the icons size.

Comment: even I changed icon size to 20 in Appearance  but it change the icon size on desktop not the file icon and other folder icon

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome tweak tools with help of [this article](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/) and change the icons theme

[image: gnome tweak tools Appearance tab]

and now it's looks satisfied to me.

[image]